# searching inside a serialised value stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, serialization

I have a table for real estate properties in which features for a real estate property are stored in serialised array. Example, a house can have wifi, pool, garden and so on other miscellaneous features. These features form a list, array with values, and are serialised and stored in table column named features. When I have to display these features I fetch the serialise array, unserialise it and display it. Now, using this table, how can I search for a house which has Wifi AND Pool? Secondly, this structure was good till the time search was out of scope but I am willing to modify it if there are strong reasons, apart from search, to change it.

**Update**
The feature wifi can be spelled as "Wifi" or "WiFi available" or "equipped with wifi" or anything. So wifi is a keyword and features are actually input by property owners so similar features can differ. Hence the idea was to save features in a serilised array

Comment: the problem is your db structure, storing data like that is plain wrong. And, no, it was never *good*. Add a features table

Comment: @Dagon, I know this, I am willing to modify it. However I can not modify it just to accommodate search as changing the existing setup will mean invitation to more problems and bugs.

Comment: it would actully aid, all select,update and insert queries. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @Dagon, you should also read about why and what not to normalize, having a separate table may be good in certain scenario but if I have to just display data it will be an overhead to query two tables.

Comment: you not just displaying, your searching  and obviously adding. guess you can lead a horse to water ...

Comment: @Dagon, you are right about adding and fetching but searching was a late feature, seems I may go for regex option and if that doesn't work out I will be modifying db, I have added some more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPs serialize format (or JSON) are no native data types in SQL. But XML for example would be. But that's often likewise overkill.

An alternative to the separate tables approach would be a CSV list of present features (native to SQL thanks to `FIND_IN_SET`).

Otherwise you can use some guesswork to prefilter the search query with `WHERE options REGEXP 's:4:"Pool";b:1'` when you want to keep the serialized data blob. (You would need to know the exact serialization scheme for each property you are looking after.)

For data sets that do not concern the database I consider that appropriate even. But since you are using the DB *mostly* for searching jus that data blob, you should reconsider.

Comment: you really think this is a better idea than normalization of the db design?

Comment: Your 08/15 database normalization advise without consideration for the use case is getting dated.

Comment: I am considering the Regex approach, search is going to be a major part but I really do not want to optimize db and increase performance hit on db, my idea is to optimise and make things work for today rather than overly optimise for tomorrow which may have totally unforeseen situation

Comment: @dagon, laziness is the identity of a good developer, "Thy shalt do less" :)

Comment: @Kumar: You could get away with `REGEXP` or just `LIKE` if you know the exact serialization of the array entries. It would be more robust if you could normalize the feature names into CSV list - as `FIND_IN_SET` is really the easiest approach. (But yes, wouldn't allow for free-form entries. So would need to be a mirror column.)

Comment: DB normalisation is a standard that has stood the test of time, the odds that you will encounter a scenario where it it  counter productive is staggering low, but clearly you have your mind made up despite the evidence, why did you even bother to ask.

Comment: B.S we fire lazy programmers.

Comment: @Dagon: You are peculating the extra effort and management overhead it incurs. In practical terms the speed advantage is what makes it interesting, but not necessarily needed. If you are never going to apply a JOIN on those normalized tables, then they are not the databases business, and it's wasted effort. We fire programmers that waste company resources.

Comment: @Dagon, thank god you never interviewed me ;-) You are right and in most of the cases for a standalone system it may work. I am not sure & can not comment on your capabilities but I guess you have not come across high volume high performance web apps, the world is looking at some thing known as NoSQL or in short how not to use RDBMS and make things faster, I strongly advice you to do some reading on performance intensive web apps.

Comment: @mario it seems that I will be able to solve it by using Regex and yes, one of the column uses free form entities, you can look at the update, while googling I came around this http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/01/21/when-should-you-store-serialized-objects-in-the-database/, I am on slow network hence can not follow all the links but I have added it to my list of must study things

Comment: @Kumar: The article sounds pretty much like your case, it's a reasonable guide. I use a similar scheme for extensibility, where actual queries on the attributes are too seldom / backend-only to warrant any ALTER TABLEs. It's basically like having an document database within SQL. Not the one true concept, but workable.